# Using PhpStorm XAMPP when opening file it is using port 63442 and rather than default port, how can I change it?

Tags: xampp, phpstorm

I have Windows 10, using XAMPP local host and PhpStorm as IDE.

When I open show the php file in browser, it shows a weird URL like:

```
http://localhost:63342/index.php/index.php?_ijt=k1qvpci720mq530tq6le3f4djb
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/projectfolder/index.php
```

I have the following settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have changed these settings to show my project folder and vice versa, but the results are the same.

How do I fix that?

Comment: FYI: `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/` is the URL of the PhpStorm's built-in simple web server. It is used when no deployment entry marked as Default is found in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`, define a new web-server and select Use as Default. The entry should be in bold instead of regular.

[image]

Comment: I should just make the settings as default. I thought it was already the default. So maybe I delete this question. But other people may face same problems so they have an answer.